# Reduction of a quadratic form to a canonical form

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-verification, quadratic-forms

I'm supposed to reduce following polynomial to its canonical form. But my result differs from the one given in my book, so I'm not sure if it's correct too.

$$
q = u_{xx} - u_{xy} - 2 u_{yy} + u_x + u_y = 0
$$

So, the characteristic quadratic polynomial is

$$
x^2 - xy -2y^2
$$

Here I'm using Lagrange's reduction method for quadratic polynomial:

\begin{align}
x^2 - xy -2y^2 &= (x^2 - xy + \frac{1}{4}y^2) - \frac{1}{4}y^2 - 2y^2\\
&= (x-\frac{1}{2}y)^2 - \frac{9}{4}y^2\\
&= \xi^2 - \frac{9}{4}\eta^2\\\\
&\xi = x-\frac{1}{2}y\\
&\eta = y
\end{align}

Now I can define the function $u$ like this:

$$
u(x,y) = u(\xi(x,y), \eta(x,y))
$$

Now I need to deduce $u_x$ and $u_y$ too:

\begin{align}
u_x &= u_\xi \cdot \xi_x + u_\eta \cdot \eta_x = u_\xi\\
u_y &= u_\xi \cdot \xi_y + u_\eta \cdot \eta_y = -\frac{1}{2}u_\xi + u_\eta
\end{align}

So, my canonical form looks like this:
\begin{align}
q &= u_{\xi\xi} - \frac{9}{4}u_{\eta\eta} + u_\xi - \frac{1}{2}u_\xi + u_\eta\\
&= \underline{\underline{u_{\xi\xi} - \frac{9}{4}u_{\eta\eta} + \frac{1}{2}u_\xi + u_\eta}}
\end{align}

Is my solution correct or is there a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We reduce second order PDE with constant coefficients to canonic form

$ u_{xx} - u_{xy} - 2 u_{yy} + u_x + u_y = 0$

Quadratic form:

$Q=x^2 - xy -2y^2=\left(x-\frac{y}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{3y}{2}\right)^2$

We get transform

$\xi=x,\quad\eta=\frac{x}{3}+\frac{2y}{3}$

and canonical form of PDE:

$u_{\xi\xi}-u_{\eta\eta}+u_\xi+u_\eta=0$

see:

V.S.Vladimirov, A Collection of Problems on the Equations
of Mathematical Physics, Springer, 1986

[image]

In our case
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}1 & \frac{1}{3}\\
0 & \frac{2}{3}\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reduce your characteristic quadratic polynomial and I got :

$$ Q(v)= -\frac18 (4y+x)^2+\frac 98 x^2$$
where v=(x,y)
I hope it helps

Comment: Can you explain what methods and steps you used to get to the answer? I think this would help the OP and other people viewing your post to understand a possible solution to the problem.